# How to preprocess data for training a character level RNN

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network, embedding

I am trying to train a RNN model which classifies origin of names. The data looks like attached image. I understand I have to first map the labels as an integer. I am using the following code to do that:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
encoder = LabelEncoder()
origin_label = encoder.fit_transform(origins)
```

I am having troubles figuring out what the next steps would be. I am using Keras to build this model. Thank you very much for your help.

[Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydn28.png)